# Boot2Docker vs Vagrant+Ubuntu for running docker

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, boot2docker

I understand that Boot2Docker is a minimal linux environment specifically for running Docker containers. I would like to use docker on my Mac with NFS for file sharing. But since Boot2Docker does not support NFS, I am considering running Ubuntu on the VM.

I believe Boot2Docker will boot faster than Ubuntu. But once the VM is fully booted, will there be any performance/resource overhead for Ubuntu, compared to Boot2Docker?

Comment: Please clarify the title and question. For example, in title, it looks you want to compare boot2docker and vagrant+ubuntu, but there is no vagrant inside the question.

Comment: Boot2Docker is the officially recommended method for running docker on non linux platforms. It includes a minimal linux distribution based on Tiny Core Linux. An alternative to boot2docker is to use vagrant to create a virtual machine running a minimal os like Boot2Docker OS or CoreOS. In my case, I want to run Ubuntu.